# How to make a loop for this

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

```
        If NUD_Pepperoni.Value > 0 Then 
            txtSummary.AppendText(vbNewLine + "Pepperoni" + vbTab & vbTab & NUD_Pepperoni.Text + vbTab & price.ToString("c1") + vbTab + vbTab & (NUD_Pepperoni.Value * price).ToString("c1") + vbNewLine)
        End If
        If NUD_Hawaiian.Value > 0 Then 
            txtSummary.AppendText(vbNewLine + "Hawaiian" + vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & NUD_Hawaiian.Text + vbTab & price.ToString("c1") + vbTab + vbTab & (NUD_Hawaiian.Value * price).ToString("c1") + vbNewLine)
        End If
        If NUD_Americano.Value > 0 Then 
            txtSummary.AppendText(vbNewLine + "Americano" + vbTab & vbTab & NUD_Americano.Text + vbTab & price.ToString("c1") + vbTab + vbTab & (NUD_Americano.Value * price).ToString("c1") + vbNewLine)
        End If
```

**there are 12 of them the same**

And the code below is the value I store

```
Dim Pizzalist(11, 1) As Single
```

================================================================

```
For p = 0 To 5
            Pizzalist(p, 0) = 8.5 'store the regular pizza Price
        Next
        For p = 6 To 11
            Pizzalist(p, 0) = 13.5 'store the gourmet pizza price
        Next
```

================================================================

```
Pizzalist(0, 1) = NUD_Pepperoni.Value
        Pizzalist(1, 1) = NUD_Hawaiian.Value
        Pizzalist(2, 1) = NUD_Americano.Value
        Pizzalist(3, 1) = NUD_TacoFiesta.Value
        Pizzalist(4, 1) = NUD_Margherita.Value
        Pizzalist(5, 1) = NUD_BeefOnion.Value
        Pizzalist(6, 1) = NUD_BNY.Value
        Pizzalist(7, 1) = NUD_MML.Value
        Pizzalist(8, 1) = NUD_IL.Value
        Pizzalist(9, 1) = NUD_GSS.Value
        Pizzalist(10, 1) = NUD_AC.Value
        Pizzalist(11, 1) = NUD_TMC.Value'store the amount of specific pizza
```

I looked up so many examples to try to figure out how to do this, but I couldn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a class which contained the information related to a pizza, let's call it `Pizza`, you could create a `List(Of Pizza)`. That list can be iterated over once its data has been entered, for example if the user clicked a button to calculate the price.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim pizzas As New List(Of Pizza)

    Public Class Pizza
        Public Property QuantitySelector As NumericUpDown
        Public Property UnitPrice As Decimal
        Public Property Name As String

        Public ReadOnly Property Quantity As Integer
            Get
                Return Convert.ToInt32(QuantitySelector.Value)
            End Get
        End Property

        Sub New()
            ' Empty constructor
        End Sub

        Sub New(name As String, quantitySelector As NumericUpDown, unitPrice As Decimal)
            Me.QuantitySelector = quantitySelector
            Me.UnitPrice = unitPrice
            Me.Name = name
        End Sub

    End Class

    Private Sub bnCalcPrice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnCalcPrice.Click
        Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder

        For Each pz In pizzas
            If pz.Quantity > 0 Then
                sb.Append(vbNewLine & pz.Name & vbTab & vbTab & pz.Quantity & vbTab & pz.UnitPrice.ToString("c1") & vbTab & vbTab & (pz.Quantity * pz.UnitPrice).ToString("c1") & vbNewLine)
            End If
        Next

        txtSummary.Text = sb.ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub InitPizzas()
        Dim regularPrice = 8.5D ' Use Decimal values for money.
        Dim premiumPrice = 13.5D

        pizzas.Add(New Pizza("Hawaiian", NUD_Hawaiian, premiumPrice))
        pizzas.Add(New Pizza("Americano", NUD_Americano, premiumPrice))
        ' etc.

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitPizzas()

    End Sub

End Class
```

You could add code to add up the individual prices for each type of pizza too.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a solution for you. Andrew has replied in the meantime while I was busy but I don't want to withhold that from you.
Like Andrew said, I would change the whole concept. I wrote a class with the most important properties of a pizza. You can change the amount in your restaurant kitchen. The data is saved in a `List(of ClassPizza)`. As Andrew said, you can then iterate over this list and take advantage of the properties. For example sort by property xy. Maybe by best-before dates?

You can save the data in a text file. (Of course, it can be done better / differently but we don't want to exaggerate today). These data are read in when the program starts. (The very first time there is of course no data, just click on ‘cancel’ in the OpenfileDialog).

When new goods arrive, you can click on the button "bring new pizzas in store" and enter everything. A second form opens for this. Care is taken to ensure that no input errors are made (for example, quantity 0 makes no sense – the text then turns red).

The current stock is displayed in the 12 text boxes.

This is **Form1.vb**:

[image: FormMain]

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE") ' change this to your language, for example "en-GB"
    Private ReadOnly All_my_pizzas_List As New List(Of ClassPizza)
    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
            tb.Text = "0"
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormMain_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        Dim Path As String
        Using OFD1 As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFD1.Title = "pick file to open"
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Text file", ".txt"))
            OFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
            If OFD1.ShowDialog() = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Path = OFD1.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        'read all Text
        Dim RAT() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        If RAT.Length = 0 Then Return

        For i As Integer = 1 To RAT.Length - 3 Step 1
            If RAT(i) = "#" Then
                All_my_pizzas_List.Add(New ClassPizza(CType(RAT(i + 1), ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza), CUShort(RAT(i + 2)), CDec(RAT(i + 3))))
            End If
        Next

        Update_Textboxes()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Update_Textboxes()
        Dim NUD_Pepperoni, NUD_Hawaiian, NUD_Americano, NUD_TacoFiesta, NUD_Margherita, NUD_BeefOnion, NUD_BNY, NUD_MML, NUD_IL, NUD_GSS, NUD_AC, NUD_TMC As Integer
        For Each piz As ClassPizza In All_my_pizzas_List
            Select Case piz.Type_of_pizza
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_Pepperoni
                    NUD_Pepperoni += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_Hawaiian
                    NUD_Hawaiian += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_Americano
                    NUD_Americano += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_TacoFiesta
                    NUD_TacoFiesta += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_Margherita
                    NUD_Margherita += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_BeefOnion
                    NUD_BeefOnion += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_BNY
                    NUD_BNY += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_MML
                    NUD_MML += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_IL
                    NUD_IL += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_GSS
                    NUD_GSS += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_AC
                    NUD_AC += 1
                Case ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza.NUD_TMC
                    NUD_TMC += 1
                Case Else
                    Exit Select
            End Select
        Next

        TextBox_Pepperoni.Text = NUD_Pepperoni.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_Hawaiian.Text = NUD_Hawaiian.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_Americano.Text = NUD_Americano.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_TacoFiesta.Text = NUD_TacoFiesta.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_Margherita.Text = NUD_Margherita.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_BeefOnion.Text = NUD_BeefOnion.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_BNY.Text = NUD_BNY.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_MML.Text = NUD_MML.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_IL.Text = NUD_IL.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_GSS.Text = NUD_GSS.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_AC.Text = NUD_AC.ToString(Deu)
        TextBox_TMC.Text = NUD_TMC.ToString(Deu)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_toStore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_toStore.Click
        Using FNP As New Form_new_pizza
            FNP.GetData()
            If FNP.ShowDialog = DialogResult.Yes Then
                For i As UInt16 = 0US To FNP.Amount - 1US Step 1US
                    All_my_pizzas_List.Add(New ClassPizza(CType(FNP.SI, ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza), 1US, FNP.price))
                Next
            End If
        End Using
        Update_Textboxes()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_change_values_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_change_values.Click
        ' this is still empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Save.Click
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' User can choose where to save the database text file and the program will save it.
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim Path As String
        Using SFD1 As New CommonSaveFileDialog
            SFD1.Title = "write data into text file"
            SFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Text file", ".txt"))
            SFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
            If SFD1.ShowDialog() = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Path = SFD1.FileName & ".txt"
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        Using textfile As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Path, True, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            textfile.WriteLine("Status of this file [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss]: " & Date.Now.ToString("G", Deu))

            For Each pizza As ClassPizza In All_my_pizzas_List
                textfile.WriteLine("#") ' Marker
                textfile.WriteLine(pizza.Type_of_pizza)
                textfile.WriteLine(pizza.stored_amount)
                textfile.WriteLine(pizza.price)
            Next

            textfile.Close()
        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the code of the **ClassPizza.vb**

```
Public NotInheritable Class ClassPizza
    Public Enum Types_of_pizza
        NUD_Pepperoni
        NUD_Hawaiian
        NUD_Americano
        NUD_TacoFiesta
        NUD_Margherita
        NUD_BeefOnion
        NUD_BNY
        NUD_MML
        NUD_IL
        NUD_GSS
        NUD_AC
        NUD_TMC
    End Enum
    Public Type_of_pizza As Types_of_pizza

    Public stored_amount As UInt16 = 0US

    ''' <summary>
    ''' in $
    ''' </summary>
    Public price As Decimal

    Public Sub New(ByVal type As Types_of_pizza, ByVal storedAmount As UInt16, price As Decimal)
        Me.Type_of_pizza = type
        Me.stored_amount = storedAmount
        Me.price = price
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the code of that second Form (**Form_new_pizza.vb**)

[image: Form_new_pizza]

```
Public NotInheritable Class Form_new_pizza
    Public Amount As UInt16
    Public price As Decimal
    Public SI As Integer

    Public Sub GetData()
        For Each _item As Object In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(ClassPizza.Types_of_pizza))
            ListBox1.Items.Add(_item)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form_new_pizza_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_Amount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox_Amount.TextChanged
        Dim success As Boolean = UInt16.TryParse(TextBox_Amount.Text, Amount)
        If success AndAlso Amount > 0US Then
            TextBox_Amount.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 200, 0) 'Green
        Else
            TextBox_Amount.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_price_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox_price.TextChanged
        Dim success As Boolean = Decimal.TryParse(TextBox_price.Text, price)
        If success Then
            TextBox_price.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 200, 0) 'Green
        Else
            TextBox_price.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> (-1) Then
            SI = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_OK.Click
        If SI <> (-1) AndAlso Amount > 0US Then
            Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes
        Else
            Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.No
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Of course, one can expand everything and do it better than me, but you can start, and understand the concept.

**By the way**

You should set ‘Option Strict’ to `On` in the project properties so that you are advised to convert data types. Also set ‘Option Infer’ to `Off` so that you always have to write down the data type ("As Integer", "As Double", ...). The latter, however, is a matter of taste.
Also, you should remove the VB6 namespace as VB6 features are deprecated.
If you need control characters (such as NewLine), you can write `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars`
.
[image: How to use Option Strict]

[image: how to not use VB6 (uncheck the box)]

====================================

Please note that I am using a FileDialog that I downloaded from Visual Studios' own Nuget Package Manager. See image. You don't have to do that, but I prefer this FileDialog because it offers more options than the one that is already included.

[image: OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog]